# Virtualhost priority

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost

I have my apache server set up and I subdomains are linked to an application which will then find the appropriate database to work with or exit if it does not exist

So for that I have an *.domain.tld

But now I do need some subdomains for the server apps for example phpmyadmin.domain.tld

So I have set it up like this

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/phpmyadmin"
ServerName phpmyadmin.domain.tld
<Directory "/var/www/phpmyadmin">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /var/www/hidden/app/public
ServerName *.domain.tld
<Directory "/var/www/hidden/app/public">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But this way it always goes to phpmyadmin wathever I give
test.domain.tld
phpmyadmin.domain.tld
helpme.domain.tld
etc.

And If I put the second virtualhost (the *.domain.tld one)
It wont go to phpmyadmin.domain.tld but just to the application

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

Still not working

This way it shows only phpmyadmin whatever I go to test.domain.tld phpmyadmin.domain.tld etc.

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin
<Directory "/var/www/phpmyadmin">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerName phpmyadmin.domain.tld
ServerAlias phpmyadmin.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /var/www/hidden/app/public
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias *.domain.tld
<Directory "/var/www/hidden/app/public">
Allowoverride All
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This way it only shows the app whatever I go to test.domain.tld phpmyadmin.domain.tld etc

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /var/www/hidden/app/public
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias *.domain.tld
<Directory "/var/www/hidden/app/public">
Allowoverride All
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin
<Directory "/var/www/phpmyadmin">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerName phpmyadmin.domain.tld
ServerAlias phpmyadmin.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

apachectl -S output

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:*                    phpmyadmin.domain.tld (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1015)
*:*                    domain.tld (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1025)
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `NameVirtualHost *` to your configuration.

(If that doesn't do the trick, provide the output from `apachectl -S`.)

Comment: updated original question, I said it was half working yesterday but I believe it was just cached because now it just is still not working at all, and yes I do restart apache every time I make changes

Comment: @Dylan You still don't have `NameVirtualHost *` in your configuration?

Comment: I had it uncommented already but it was NameVirtualHost *:80
Even tough I expected that to be fine, I removed the :80 and it works now. Seems odd and maybe it is something else but I'am glad it works now (I'am getting the feeling the paged were cached and gave me different results)

Comment: @Dylan A `*:80` setting would definitely cause it to not function.  It needs to match exactly to your vhosts.

Comment: Oh now I understand it conflicts with the <VirtualHost *>, so if I'd want NameVirtualHist *:80 to work I had to go for <VirtualHost *:80>?

Comment: @Dylan Yup, exactly!

Answer (score 2):

The `ServerName` directive does not allow the use of wildcards. For this you need the `ServerAlias`.

So make it something like

```
ServerName somethingelse.domain.tld
ServerAlias *.domain.tld
```

Comment: And now combine the reply of @ShaneMadden and mine and you'll get a working situation ;)

Comment: Thank you very much sir, strange that webmin doesn't have an option for this (no problems doing it manually but I'd expect if they offer a GUI for it, it supports common features)

Comment: Still does not function optimal, if I go to phpmyadmin.domain.tld it works as soon as I log on and it goes to phpmyadmin.domain.tld/index.php it goes to the app (*.domain.tld)

Comment: @Dylan Can you post your new VirtualHost configuration? To get a complete overview and check for the reason for that to happen?

Comment: updated orginal question with new virtualhost

Comment: @Dylan It seems then like Apache can't match the hostname. Or like `NameVirtualHost *` is not included in the configuration. Apache takes the **first** VirtualHost that matches. If you put the wildcard one first in the file, it's expected behavior that then also phpmyadmin.domain.tld is handled by the wildcard. So the wildcard should go last. If Apache can't find the requested hostname __at all__, it is again taking the first VirtualHost it can find. Are there no other VirtualHosts defined? Does this maybe help in debugging yourself?